# rake neo4j:create error rake aborted

Tags: rake, neo4j

```
>sudo rake neo4j:create --trace                                     [ 6:18PM]
```

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'neo4j:create'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in`run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in`run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19

What may be the probable reason for this error. I am following the maxdemarzi introduction to neo4j and d3.js.

I will be thankful if some one can suggest the solution 
https://github.com/maxdemarzi/d3_js_intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the project so it works now.  Please run:

```
git pull                             # Get the latest code
bundle install                       # Update the project gems
rake neo4j:reset_yes_i_am_sure       # Reset the Neo4j Server
rake neo4j:create
```

Ping me if you still have trouble.

Regards,
Max